# Flutter IOS build failed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

dependencies:
add_2_calendar: ^1.4.0

```
*** BUILD FAILED **

fatal error : module 'add_2_calendar' not found
@import add_2_calendar;
1 error generated.
```

[full error screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6yt.jpg)

Used "add_2_calendar: ^1.4.0" dependency, when I build IOS got the errors.

We download the dependency and add manually into folder also, but it does not work.

version using in my project :

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale
> en-IN)
>    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /Users/manicpod/Downloads/flutter
>    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (3 months ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
>    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
>    • Dart version 2.9.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
>    • Android SDK at /Users/manicpod/Library/Android/sdk
>    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
>    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>    • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
>    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
>    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

Comment: Please include code / errors as text, not as images.